# Repeating functions on sequentially-labeled dataframes

Tags: r

A question that is undoubtedly easy to solve for an R expert.

I need to repeat a number of functions on dataframes that are sequentially labeled (before merging them all together). For example, I might need to do the following:

```
# READ IN DATAFILES & LABEL DF'S 
df1 <- read.csv(file="file_A.csv",head=TRUE) 
df2 <- read.csv(file="file_B.csv",head=TRUE) 
df3 <- read.csv(file="file_C.csv",head=TRUE)

# TURN DF'S INTO DATA TABLES
df1<-data.table(df1)
df2<-data.table(df2)
df3<-data.table(df3)

# CHANGE VARIABLE TO POSIX
df1$date <-as.POSIXct(df1$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df2$date <-as.POSIXct(df2$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df3$date <-as.POSIXct(df3$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# FILTER BY DATE RANGE
date_filter<-as.POSIXct("2012-01-01 01:01:01")
df1<-subset(df1, df1$date>date_filter)
df2<-subset(df2, df2$date>date_filter)
df3<-subset(df3, df3$date>date_filter)

# AGGREGATE OVER A UNIQUE ID 
df1<-df1[,(sum(var)), by=list(id)] 
df2<-df2[,(sum(var)), by=list(id)] 
df2<-df2[,(sum(var)), by=list(id)] 

# FINALLY, MERGE TOGETHER
df <-merge(df1,df2, by="id",all=TRUE)
```

You get the idea--only I need to do this for 25 dataframes, not 3.  I have a suspicion that I can make R repeat functions by creating a vector (`df_nums<-c(1:25)`)) and then using a function to loop over all of my data frames, but I don't know how to do it.

Please help! Thanks!

**Edit:** Thanks to Arun, I'm up to this for my actual code:

```
out<- lapply(1:length(files), function(idx) {
  df <- as.data.table(read.csv(files[idx], header = TRUE))
  df$date <- as.POSIXct(df$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  date_filter <- as.POSIXct("2012-11-13 01:01:01")
  df <- subset(df, df$date > date_filter)
  df <- df[, .N, by = list(id)] 
})
out<-data.table(out)
out.merge <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by="id", all=T), out)
```

**Edit 2:**  After running the following syntax, I appear to have `data.tables` nested in `out.`  For example,

```
> head(out)
            out
1: <data.table>
2: <data.table>
3: <data.table>
4: <data.table>
5: <data.table>
6: <data.table>
```

How do I access these `data.tables` to see if everything worked correctly?

Comment: Resolved! Human error was responsible -- an extra CSV file snuck into my folder, and it didn't have the variable "date" which was mucking everything up.  I should have double-checked by printing "files." Thank you so much for your help, and sorry if this wasted any time for you!

Comment: One final question! If I don't have time to worry about the "reduce" command, how do I manually access the data.tables created so I can merge them???

Comment: @Arun - Do I embed the function inside of the reduce command? Sorry to be obtuse :(

Comment: Hi @Arun - please see updates. Merge isn't working because R appears to be confused about the unique identifier, which is always numeric (but read in as a factor, it seems).

Comment: Changing it to a `data.table` made the command work, but it appears that now there are `data.tables` nested within `out`. Updated again above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `list.files` to obtain all the CSV files from the directory and use `lapply` to recurse, in this manner:

```
# Thanks Matthew for correcting the pattern string
files <- list.files("path_to_files", full.names = TRUE, pattern="\\.csv$") 
out <- lapply(1:length(files), function(idx) {
    df <- as.data.table(read.csv(files[idx], header = TRUE))
    df$date <- as.POSIXct(df$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    date_filter <- as.POSIXct("2012-01-01 01:01:01")
    df <- subset(df, df$date > date_filter)
    df <-df[, (sum(var)), by = list(id)]
})
```

You can use `do.call(rbind, out)` or `do.call(cbind, out)` to bind all results by row or columns.

**Edit:** After @roody's question about outer join. Something like this?

```
out.merge <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by="id", all=T), out)
```

Comment: Hi there--Thanks so much. I may be wrong, but I don't think that I can use `rbind` because I need to do an outer join, so that I have a row for every unique ID (even if that unique ID is not in every data.frame.)  Thoughts?

Comment: @Arun, +1, but you need `pattern='\\.csv$'`. what you have now would match any number of names containing 'csv'. Also, remember that '*' in R regex is '0 or more of the previous character', not the a wildcard.

Comment: @roody Have a look at `merge_recurse` in the package **reshape** (not **reshape2**). There is probably a slick data.table solution as well if you poke around a bit.

Comment: @Arun - I'm getting an error message that says `"do not know how to convert 'df$date' to class "POSIXct"`.  I've double checked to make sure that the command works when I run the commands for each df sequentially, and it does...What do you think?

Comment: Yeah, me neither.  I copied that code from the lines that I ran for each data table sequentially, and it works. I have no idea what's going on...

Comment: Updated!  There's an extra line where I create a dummy variable, which is what I sum on.