# Repeating sequential functions when creating multiple lists/matrices/dataframes within `lapply`

Tags: r, lapply

This question is an elaboration on a previous question that I'd asked about [repeating functions on sequentially-labeled dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442173/repeating-functions-on-sequentially-labeled-dataframes).

In the past, I needed to make minor alterations to `data.tables` read in from a folder to R (e.g. changing dates, recoding).

Now, however, my goals are a bit more complex: I'd like to read in several text files from a folder, take a random sample from those character vectos, read the random sample into a corpus (using the package `tm`) and then generate a new `data.frame` that has a list of words/phrases and their frequencies.

The code I've developed so far is as follows:

```
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 1, max = 5)) # Finds words or phrases
files <- list.files("~/path/", full.names = TRUE, pattern="\\.txt$") # Reads in files

out <- lapply(1:length(files), function(x) {
  df <- scan(files[x], what="", sep="\n") # Read in files
  df<-sample(c(df),size=1500,replace=F) # Take random sample
  corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(df)) # Create corpus
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, tolower)
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
  tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer)) #Create term document matrix
  m <- as.matrix(tdm)
  v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
  d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v) # Create new dataframe with words & their frequencies
})
```

However, although this function works, I'm not sure how to access only the data.frames `d` while discarding the rest?  Does `out` contain all of the objects created in `lapply`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lapply` function returns a list containing the values returned by the specified function.  In your example, the function returns only the data frame that is assigned to `d`, so `out` will be a list containing only the `d` data frames.  All of the other objects created by the function (such as `tdm`, `m`, and `v`) will be discarded, which seems to be what you want.

You can access the data frames in `out` by indexing them, as in out[[1]], with lapply, as in `lapply(out, function(d) d$word)`, or by combining them with `do.call('rbind', out)`.

Comment: Thanks! This is a bit obtuse, but how do I then access those dataframes?  I'd like to create a new `data.frame` of the top 100 terms for each sample (thus some sort of join where the words are in one column, and the frequencies from different samples are in other columns...)

Comment: You can access the data frames by indexing them, as in `out[[1]]`, or perhaps using `lapply` again, as in `lapply(out, function(d) d$word)`, or by combining them with `do.call('rbind', out)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks however this is what I got

```
do.call('rbind', out)
```

> Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) :    numbers of columns of
>   arguments do not match

I used

```
lapply(seq_along(d.names), 
       function(i,x) {assign(paste0("a",i),x[[i]], envir=.GlobalEnv)},
       x=out)
```

I wanted to retain the original dataframe names though and so I did this

```
lapply(seq_along(d.names), 
   function(i,x) {assign(paste0(d.names[i],i),x[[i]], envir=.GlobalEnv)},
   x=out)
```

and it worked

Appreciate your input